# Is it possible to download software using R?

Tags: r

I am writing a user-friendly function to import Access tables using R. I have found that most of the steps will have to be done outside of R, but I want to keep most of this within the script if possible. The first step is to download a Database driver from microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255. 
I am wondering if it is possible to download software from inside R, and what function/package I can use? I have looked into download.file but this seems to be for downloading information files rather than software.
Edit: I have tried 
    install_url(https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/3/24375141-E08D- 
    4803-AB0E-10F2E3A07AAA/AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe)

But I get an error:
Downloading package from url: https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/3/24375141-E08D-4803-AB0E-10F2E3A07AAA/AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe
Installation failed: Don't know how to decompress files with extension exe

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: There's an R way to import Access tables, if you want it.  I have done it but I'd have to find the code.

Comment: @Elin I have to first download the driver because when I try the direct R way to import Access tables, I get errors since I have 32bit Access and 64bit R. I would change the bits of R manually but this would make my function less user friendly again

Comment: That's frustrating.  Did you use https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ImportExport/ImportExport.pdf  ?  Are you doing this in a package or a script?

Comment: you can use `download.file` to download it, and `system` to run the installation